# How to set OnDelete cascade in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, cascading-deletes, entity-framework-6.1

I have two tables, BookCategory & Books. There can be multiple books for one category.
I am using entity framework. 
On deleting particular BookCategory, I want to delete all books of same category.

I am not sure where to set the rule of OnDelete = Cascade.
Following is my code.

Please let me know if any more information is required.

1] My Database (bookCatalog.Context.cs)

```
namespace LearningEF
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class bookCatalogEntities : DbContext
    {
        public bookCatalogEntities()
            : base("name=bookCatalogEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();

        }


        public virtual DbSet<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

    }
}
```

2] My Book Class (Book.cs)

```
namespace LearningEF
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Book
    {
        public Book()
        {

        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Category { get; set; }

        public virtual BookCategory BookCategory { get; set; }

    }
}
```

3] My BookCategories class (BookCategory.cs)

```
namespace LearningEF
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class BookCategory
    {

        public BookCategory()
        {
            this.Books = new HashSet<Book>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }

    }
}
```

4] Diagram xml (bookCatalog.edmx.diagram)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
 <!-- EF Designer content (DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY BELOW HERE) -->
  <edmx:Designer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
    <!-- Diagram content (shape and connector positions) -->
    <edmx:Diagrams>
      <Diagram DiagramId="3da0fdfb8bce456da4d1833a61ed8d58" Name="Diagram1">
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="bookCatalogModel.Author" Width="1.5" PointX="0.75" PointY="1.25" IsExpanded="true" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="bookCatalogModel.BookCategory" Width="1.5" PointX="0.75" PointY="5.25" IsExpanded="true" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="bookCatalogModel.Book" Width="1.5" PointX="3" PointY="0.875" IsExpanded="true" />
        <EntityTypeShape EntityType="bookCatalogModel.sysdiagram" Width="1.5" PointX="2.75" PointY="4.75" IsExpanded="true" />
        <AssociationConnector Association="bookCatalogModel.FK_Books_BookCategories" ManuallyRouted="false"   />
        <AssociationConnector Association="bookCatalogModel.BookAuthors" ManuallyRouted="false" />
      </Diagram>
    </edmx:Diagrams>
  </edmx:Designer>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

[image]

but while deleting BookCategory getting following error.

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
```

Here is my code of deleting category

```
BookCategory deleteBookCat = dbCatlog.BookCategories.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id.Equals(1));
            dbCatlog.BookCategories.Remove(deleteBookCat);
            dbCatlog.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: You have to set it inside your model. Open the edmx with the designer and select the line connecting your entities in the properties window you will have the OnDelete property to change.

Comment: Yes I have done that, will try to attach screen shot.But still got error.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that EF will only delete those that are currently loaded inside the context that fires the delete it will not clear the whole database, so make sure everything is loaded.

Comment: I haven't loaded any Books, selected one category using LINQ and tried to delete the same, in addition want to delete all books of that category, OnDelete cascade is marked as true.

Comment: And there is the problem EF will only mark those books to be removed that are loaded and visible through the category.Books property. And I think you want the End2 OnDelete set to cascade.

Comment: I am not sure about all other things than where OnDelete should be setted. It should be on BookCategories, I am dam sure about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution, Actually it is not solution, cause it was mistake that in Database OnDelete Cascade was not set. Once it is configured, Ondelete Cascade of EF doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this (recordToDelete is your instance of BookCategory)

```
  recordToDelete.Books.ToList().ForEach(p => db.Books.Remove(p));


  db.BookCategory(recordToDelete).State = EntityState.Deleted;


  db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I will try out ur suggestion, but ideally what I want is that, is there any property which can be set for cascade = true. I have seen somewhere on net, but doesn't remember.by the way thanks 4 ur time, & will appreciate if more attempt is made to solve this.

Comment: Set the "cascade delete"s of the foreign keys and reflect that in your Entity Model. After that the database will make the necessary operations to maintain the referential integrity when you delete some entity.

Comment: Friend didn;t understand what u want to say.

Comment: you can set the cascade delete in your database schema. If this property is setted you can only delete parent record and the database will delete the children.

Comment: I got solution, issue was OnDelete Cascade was not set in my database.And if it is true in database then no need to set it again in code in EF. Thanks 4 help mate.